# Alternatives to Using BuildProviders with Web Applications

Tags: visual-studio, web-applications, build-process, buildprovider

I've read that you cannot use a BuildProvider with Web Applications in Visual Studio (or more specifically, you can use it, but your code isn't part of the project)

Are there any other ways to generate code on the fly using a Web Application project?
With or without using third-party tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [T4 templates](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/T4TextTemplateTransformationToolkitCodeGenerationBestKeptVisualStudioSecret.aspx) in Visual Studio?

Comment: Actually, I have -- was pretty interesting but didn't devote a whole lot of time to figuring it out. The MVC team actually ended up doing what I was trying to do in MVC2 so I didn't really work on it anymore :)